# redux-observable you provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-observable, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using the fbsdk to get user details in an ajax request. So it makes sense to do this in a redux-observable epic. The way the fbsdk request goes, it doesn't have a `.map()` and `.catch()` it takes the success and failure callbacks:

code:

```
export const fetchUserDetailsEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>,
  store
): Observable<CategoryAction> =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => {
    getDetails(store)
  })

const getDetails = store => {
  console.log(store)
  let req = new GraphRequest(
    '/me',
    {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        fields: {
          string: 'email,first_name,last_name'
        }
      }
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        store.dispatch(fetchUserDetailsRejected(err))
      } else {
        store.dispatch(fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(res))
      }
    }
  )

  return new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(req).start()
}
```

It gives the error:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You
>   can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

How do I return an observable from the epic so this error goes away?

Attempt at `bindCallback` from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43876394/3935156):

```
const getDetails = (callBack, details) => {
  let req = new GraphRequest(
    '/me',
    {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        fields: {
          string: 'email,first_name,last_name'
        }
      }
    },
    callBack(details)
  )

  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(req).start()
}

const someFunction = (options, cb) => {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    cb = options
    options = null
  }
  getDetails(cb, null)
}

const getDetailsObservable = Observable.bindCallback(someFunction)

export const fetchUserDetailsEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>
): Observable<CategoryAction> =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => {
    getDetailsObservable()
      .mergeMap(details => {
        return Observable.of(fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(details))
      })
      .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchUserDetailsRejected(error)))
  })
```

Getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into source code of [`GraphRequestManager .start`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBGraphRequestManager.js):

```
start(timeout: ?number) {
  const that = this;
  const callback = (error, result, response) => {
    if (response) {
      that.requestCallbacks.forEach((innerCallback, index, array) => {
        if (innerCallback) {
          innerCallback(response[index][0], response[index][1]);
        }
      });
    }
    if (that.batchCallback) {
      that.batchCallback(error, result);
    }
  };

  NativeGraphRequestManager.start(this.requestBatch, timeout || 0, callback);
}
```

As you can see it does return nothing, so effectively `undefined`. Rx `mergeMap` requires an instance of Observable or something compatible with it ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120680/how-does-rxjs-mergemap-work/42272148#42272148)).

Since you dispatch further actions, you can modify your original code like that:

```
export const fetchUserDetailsEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>,
  store
): Observable<CategoryAction> =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).do(() => { // .mergeMap changed to .do
    getDetails(store)
  })

const getDetails = store => {
  console.log(store)
  let req = new GraphRequest(
    '/me',
    {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        fields: {
          string: 'email,first_name,last_name'
        }
      }
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        store.dispatch(fetchUserDetailsRejected(err))
      } else {
        store.dispatch(fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(res))
      }
    }
  )

  return new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(req).start()
}
```

To be honest I find your second attempt bit better / less coupled. To make it working you could do something like:

```
const getDetails = Observable.create((observer) => {
  let req = new GraphRequest(
    '/me',
    {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        fields: {
          string: 'email,first_name,last_name'
        }
      }
    },
    (error, details) => {
      if (error) {
        observer.error(error)
      } else {
        observer.next(details)
        observer.complete()
      }
    }
  )

  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(req).start()
})

export const fetchUserDetailsEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>
): Observable<CategoryAction> =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => {
    getDetails()
      .map(details => fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(details)) // regular .map should be enough here
      .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchUserDetailsRejected(error)))
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember well how was working `redux-observable` before using `RxJS >= 6` but I'll try to help ;)

First, you don't need to dispatch yourself, redux-observable will do it for you. [In this article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/redux-observable-ec0b00d2eb52), they show how it works under the hood, so they call dispatch, but you don't have to. In the new implementation, they removed `store` as a second argument in favor of a `state` stream:

```
const epic = (action$, store) => { ... //before
const epic = (action$, state$) => { ... //after
```

But most importantly, **the problem you experience is that you don't return a stream of actions**, but a single (dispatched) action.
[From their website](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html):

> It is a function which takes a stream of actions and returns a stream of actions.

So I think a quick solution would be to return observables from your callback:

```
(err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    return Observable.of(fetchUserDetailsRejected(err))
  }
  return Observable.of(fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(res))
}
```

I will update the answer based on your comments. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I get the same error I think because it takes a long time to get to the code which returns those observables and it races off and returns undefined straight away

Comment: It should not be linked to the time it takes to fullfill the request. I usually use the rxjs `ajax`  to make my API calls (or before transformed Axios promises with `fromPromise`), so I have never dealt with callbacks. Have you checked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862483/redux-observable-how-to-return-an-action-from-a-callback)? It seems related to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive this seems the possible reason for `undefined`. You are returning `undefined` in `mergeMap` callback.

This

```
action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => {
    getDetails(store)
})
```

should be either

```
action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => getDetails(store))
```

or

```
action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => {
    return getDetails(store)
})
```

Comment: That callback is returning `undefined`.  Anyway, I understand the problem now.  Try wrapping `getDetails` function in a `Promise`, resolve/reject it when you get the response.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like @artur grzesiak has a correct answer, but for completeness this is how I think `bindCallback` can be used.

The only issue I have with Artur's answer is I don't think we need to catch the error in the epic, since `fetchUserDetailsRejected` is an error-handling action (presumably the reducer deals with it appropriately).

I used this reference [RxJs Static Public Methods: bindCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback)

> Give it a function f of type f(x, callback) and it will return a function g that when called as g(x) will output an Observable.

```js
// This callback receives the results and returns one or other action (non-observable)
const callback = (err, res) => {
  return err 
    ? fetchUserDetailsRejected(err)
    : fetchUserDetailsFulfilled(res)
}

// Here is the graph request uncluttered by concerns about the epic
const getDetails = (store, callback) => {
  console.log(store)
  let req = new GraphRequest(
    '/me',
    {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        fields: {
          string: 'email,first_name,last_name'
        }
      }
    },
    callback
  )
  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(req).start()
}

// This bound function wraps the action returned from callback in an Observable
const getDetails$ = Observable.bindCallback(getDetails).take(1)

// The epic definition using bound callback to return an Observable action
export const fetchUserDetailsEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = 
  (action$: ActionsObservable<*>, store): Observable<CategoryAction> =>
    action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_DETAILS).mergeMap(() => getDetails$(store))
```